# Apache2: ports.conf vs Vhost

Tags: apache-2.2, debian-buster

The Ports on Apache can be changed on two positions:

- `/sites-available/000-default.conf`
- `ports.conf`

Per Default, both .conf Files dictates Apache to listen on Port 80.

I want to set Apache to listen on a specific port. It seems, that `ports.conf` overrides the values of `000-default.conf`

Where is the correct place to change the Port when the Server runs only on one single IP-Adress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ports can be changed in `ports.conf` alone. The various site configs contain definitions of what to serve on the open ports. This means that if you define a `VirtualHost` like this:

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:1234>
```

but you don't have a corresponding `Listen 1234` directive, then the `VirtualHost` definition above is a no-op.

So in order to make Apache listen on an other port, you need to include the `Listen` directive in `ports.conf` (technically any other file would do, but it is a good idea to write config snippets where they belong), and make a `VirtualHost` entry in one of the config files in `sites-available`. After this, use `a2ensite` to enable the created config.